# R gsub remove SQL comments from a character string

Tags: r, regex

In R, I have a character string `w` and would like to get rid of the SQL commented parts i.e. the characters between `/*` and `*/`.

This is what I have tried so far, but it doesn't quite work....

```
 w <- "ldsjflsdj /* hhhhhhhhsdlfjlsj */ dskfhjsdkjfhsd"
 gsub("[/**/]","",w)
```

The ideal output would be something like:

```
`ldsjflsdj dskfhjsdkjfhsd`
```

How do I achieve this?

I am pretty sure it's simple I'm just not an expert in `regex`

Thanks,

HLM

Comment: What about end-of-line comments, ie `-- this is a comment`?

Comment: I had dealt with that in a previous grep...i think it was the `/*` that was annoying me as i didn't know how to do a between two special characters logic...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that it's as illegal as in C to have nested comments, the following should work:

```
gsub("/\\*.*?\\*/", "", w);
```

Comment: Maybe `gsub("/\\*.*\\*/", "", w)`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto: Why a greedy quantifier?

Comment: (Mostly because I don't know much about regex....). Your answer works fine on the example here. +1

Answer (score 2):

Using the [qdap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qdap/index.html) package's `genX`:

```
library(qdap)
genX(w, "/\\*", "/\\*")

## [1] "ldsjflsdj dskfhjsdkjfhsd"
```